# Pentaho Data Integration (Spoon) Import XML with nested elements

Tags: xml, xpath, pentaho, kettle, spoon

I have the following xml data structure and I'm trying to create a transformation in Pentaho that gives the output shown in the linked image. The data has elements nested in elements and I can only seem to set the Loop XPath option to get either the main_components or the sub_components.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components>
    <main_component>
        <name>Engine</name>
        <ref_no>336820-182</ref_no>
        <oem>Ford</oem>
    </main_component>
    <main_component>
        <name>Gearbox</name>
        <ref_no>378912-009</ref_no>
        <oem>GM</oem>
    </main_component>
    <main_component>
        <name>Fuel Tank</name>
        <ref_no>378927</ref_no>
        <oem>GM</oem>
        <sub_component>
            <name>Fuel Pump</name>
            <ref_no>27182A</ref_no>
            <oem>Lucus</oem>
        </sub_component>
            <name>Contents Unit</name>
            <ref_no>1219290</ref_no>
            <oem>Honeywell</oem>
        </sub_component>
    </main_component>
</components>
```

[Required Transformation Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImppP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "XML Input Stream" and need to write small javascript code to get parent node information. (Here I have set the variable if parent node is available and read those variable if child node is available as parent information of that child)

```js
//Script here
var pName=null;
var pRef=null;
var pOem=null;


if( xml_path_level2 != null){
  pName = getVariable("VName","");
  pRef = getVariable("VRef","");
  pOem = getVariable("VOem","");
}
else{
  setVariable( "VName",Name,"s");
  setVariable( "VRef",Ref_no,"s");
  setVariable( "VOem",Oem,"s");
}
```

You can found sample from [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ORWOlteBDkgd1GFyJifoEP5h8O2hVm5-?usp=sharing)

[image]

Pleasae let me know if its ok with you.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I needed to solve the problem. Thanks for taking the time to go into the detailed solution for me